# How to access numbered state in rect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Is any way to access numbered state. for eg

```
this.setState({123:hello})
```

now how can i access this state

```
console.log(this.state.123)  //this will show error
```

Comment: Try using `this.state['123']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

> this.state[123]

You should not use numbers as a object property name however.